When exactly did the unregistered user posting experiment begin, and what is its duration?
In the meta post Should we allow unregistered users to post questions and answers?, Wipqozn mentioned that the mod team had Stack Exchange re-enable posting from unregistered users, following community support for MBraedley's suggestion. While MBraedley originally proposed running this experiment from mid-December to mid-January to capture Christmas traffic, I noticed an unregistered user posting today (November 18 UTC), which is earlier than the suggested timeframe.
When did this change take effect, and how long will the experiment continue? Is it still planned to run through mid-January?

tl;dr: November 7th to Mid January.
What Robotnik said is right. Nov 7 is when the test started, since I posted that answer within minutes of the CM team notifying the mods. The reason we started the test earlier is for two reasons: A longer duration means more data, and the CM team is really busy, so we figured it was better to get them to start the test right now while they had the time and we're focused on us. Had we waited until December, our request may have gotten lost in the shuffle of the CM team taking holiday vacations and dealing with any end-of-year things.
The end-date is just "January" at the moment. The CM team said they'll check back in with us come January, and the mod team decided that if we don't hear from the CM team by mid-Jan, that we'll reach out to them ourselves.
